# curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

Tags: php, unirest

> Warning: curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be
>   activated when an open_basedir is set .

I am trying to install Unirest and when i executed php file i got this error message

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your PHP configuration is prohibiting you from following the location. There are a few ways you could work around the problem.

- If you have root access, you could change the
  php.ini file to disable "safe_mode".
- You could also create a .htaccess file in your document root with
  php_value safe_mode off in it.
- You may be able to add ini_set('safe_mode', false); in your PHP file.